# Wrongly installed module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, scikit-learn

I tried to install sci-kit learn module in python on ubuntu. As explained in their tutorial, I did:

```
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn
```

But when, in python console, I try

```
import sklearn
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

Moreover, if I do

```
pip list
```

sklearn does not appear in the list.

And if I try:

```
sudo pip install scikit-learn
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scikit-learn in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: any chance you are using a virtualenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably caused by the folder `~/.local/lib` not appearing in your `sys.path`. You can update the `sys.path` in a couple of ways. Either set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before running the console, or just append to the `sys.path` array.

You could uninstall the module and then reinstall as root:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn ; sudo pip install scikit-learn
```

You can also just delete the `~/.local/lib` folder and reinstall the package.

Comment: uninstall is a good suggestion, but I get:
    Cannot uninstall requirement scikit-learn, not installed
    Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Perhaps you should just delete the ~/.local/lib folder. That should be equivalent to uninstalling the package. You may want to consider virtualenvwrapper as a way to handle these dependencies in future: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I'm dealing with this error when I want to remove `scikit-learn` package: `Cannot uninstall 'scikit-learn'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807511/pip-cannot-uninstall-package-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but when I used `sudo pip uninstall scikit-learn` or `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn` I'm dealing with the following error:

```
Cannot uninstall 'scikit-learn'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

---

### My problem solved by the following line:

```
sudo pip install --ignore-installed scikit-learn==0.18
```