# pip cannot uninstall <package>: "It is a distutils installed project"

Tags: python, installation, pip, distutils

I tried to install the Twilio module:

```
sudo -H pip install twilio
```

And I got this error:

```
Installing collected packages: pyOpenSSL
  Found existing installation: pyOpenSSL 0.13.1
Cannot uninstall 'pyOpenSSL'. It is a distutils installed project and             
thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which 
would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Anyone know how to uninstall pyOpenSSL?

Comment: In my case, `anaconda3` installed `vtk` and i tried to update `vtk` from `pip`.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

This error means that this package's metadata doesn't include a list of files that belong to it. **Most probably, you have installed this package via your OS' package manager, so you need to use that rather than `pip` to update or remove it, too.**

See e.g. [Upgrading to pip 10: It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall. · Issue #5247 · pypa/pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247#issuecomment-443398741) for one such example where the package was installed with `apt`.

---

Alternatively, depending on your needs, it may be more productive to not use your system Python and/or its global environment but create a private Python installation and/or environment. There are many options here including `virtualenv`, `venv`, `pyenv`, `pipenv` and installing Python from source into 
`/usr/local` or `$HOME`/`$HOME/.local` (or `/opt/<whatever>`).

---

Finally, I must comment on the often-suggested (e.g. at [pip 10 and apt: how to avoid "Cannot uninstall X" errors for distutils packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932759/pip-10-and-apt-how-to-avoid-cannot-uninstall-x-errors-for-distutils-packages)) `--ignore-installed` `pip` switch.

It *may* work (potentially for a long enough time for your business needs), but may just as well break things on the system in unpredictable ways. One thing is sure: it makes the system's configuration unsupported and thus unmaintainable -- because you have essentially overwritten files from your distribution with some other arbitrary stuff. E.g.:

- If the new files are binary incompatible with the old ones, other software from the distribution built to link against the originals will segfault or otherwise malfunction.
- If the new version has a different set of files, you'll end up with a mix of old and new files which may break dependent software as well as the package itself.
- If you change the package with your OS' package manager later, it will overwrite `pip`-installed files, with similarly unpredictable results.
- If there are things like configuration files, differences in them between the versions can also lead to all sorts of breakage.

Comment: Thank you. I took your suggestion and created a private Python installation.

Comment: What about packages installed using `sudo -H pip3 install <package>`? I usually use that instead of building virtual env. so that my personally needed packages are installed in `/usr/local`. Hence, they should not interfere with the ones installed with `apt` in `/usr`. But even with the former command, `pip` is complaining with the error the OP mentioned. @ivan_pozdeev : would you be able to complete your already nice answer with such piece of information if you do have them?

Comment: @s.k Running without `--ignore-installed` won't break stuff in the way described here. Version conflicts might happen if you install a Python package with Pip and _then_ the same package _and_ something that that depends on it with Apt. The two versions won't break each other but the dependent package might not support the newer dependency from Pip.

Comment: I was installed it using `yum` before. I have uninstalled by `yum remove python-requests` and then installed with `pip` by issuing `pip install requests'

Answer (score 86):

I had the same error and was able to resolve using the following steps:

```
  pip install --ignore-installed pyOpenSSL
```

This will install the package with latest version and then if you try to install,

```
  pip install twilio
```

It will work.

Comment: i had the same error with 'httplib2' when trying to install 'google-api-python-client', and this solution worked for me as well (linux/ubuntu), thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Generally, for similar errors, use this format:

```
pip install --ignore-installed [package name]==[package version]
```

Comment: Please, could you rationalize on the solution you are suggesting? Any drawbacks?

Comment: this one works. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was installing a package from internal git using the following command:

```sh
python -m pip install package.whl --force
```

I was doing this because I didn't want to explicitly uninstall the previous version and just replace it with a newer version. But what it also does is install all the dependencies again. I was getting the error in one of those packages. Removing `--force` fixed the problem.

I want to add, having `--ignore-installed` also worked for me. And removing `--force` is essentially doing the same thing in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this error and the only way I was able to resolve it was by manually deleting the offending directory from `site-packages`.

After doing this you may need to reinstall the packages with `--force-reinstall`.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the above comments, I understood that package a was installed with conda and the new package b that I was trying to install using pip was causing problems. I was lucky that package b had conda support so using conda to install package b solved the problem.

Comment: Ran into a similar issue with trying to install `stumpy` using `pip` when conda had already installed `llvmlite`.  Using conda to install stumpy fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, just delete the installed package in `site-packages`, then reinstall this package. To find the path of `site-packages`, you can try `pip install package name`, the path for the specific path will be printed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).