# "IndexError: list index out of range" on "import pybel"

Tags: python, django, openbabel, pybel

I'm working on a web app django, when I install openbabel and try to import pybel i've got an error

I'm using a `venv` that was activate when I did all this commands

I install openbabel like this:

`sudo apt-get install python-openbabel`

I also tried :

`sudo apt-get install openbabel libopenbabel-dev swig`

Then I did :

`pip install openbabel`

after that, I've tried to import pybel (after importing openbabel)

This is actuall result :

```
>>> import pybel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/etudiant/QuChemPedIA/QuChemPedIAProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pybel.py", line 94, in <module>
    descs = _getpluginnames("descriptors")
  File "/home/etudiant/QuChemPedIA/QuChemPedIAProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pybel.py", line 84, in _getpluginnames
    return [x.split()[0] for x in plugins]
  File "/home/etudiant/QuChemPedIA/QuChemPedIAProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pybel.py", line 84, in <listcomp>
    return [x.split()[0] for x in plugins]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help please?

Comment: You are clearly using a `venv` but there's no mention of this in your explanation. Please upgrade your instructions on how to reproduce this from a clean state (including your distro and such).

Comment: If you are installing the package into a `venv`, there's no need to install it with `apt-get` globally, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Manu mathew said, [this is a bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=862517), but not in Python's `openbabel` package but rather in the `openbabel` C library that it wraps (provided by the `openbabel` apt package).

The bug is fixed in version `openbabel/2.3.2+dfsg-3` that for your Ubuntu Xenial (judging by your Python version) [is not available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/openbabel).

**So you need to upgrade your distro. The fix is available [since Bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/openbabel) but for best results, upgrade to the latest distro release** (see below for explanation).

---

Beside that,

- **Installing `python-openbabel` apt package is useless** because [it's for Python 2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-openbabel). A package for Python 3 would be called "`python3-openbabel`" but [there's no such package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/python3-openbabel). So you do have to install the bindings from PyPI.
- Installing a Python package both globally with `apt-get` and into venv with `pip` is redundant.

  - <sub>If you are using an old distro, you also open yourself to possible breakage when you link a new bindings package from PyPI against an old C library on your system. If the bindings package builds against your local library, it is likely meant to support this version, but who knows how much this combination was tested.</sub>
- So normally, you should prefer the `apt-get` version of a Python package that wraps a local C library if one is available [if you are using the system Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807511/pip-cannot-uninstall-package-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project/53807588#53807588). You can make globally installed packages available in a venv by creating it with [`--system-site-packages`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?highlight=venv#creating-virtual-environments).

But since in this case, there's no `apt-get` version of bindings available, you have to install the bindings from PyPI. In this case, you'd better have the C library version that corresponds to the bindings' version -- i.e. probably the latest -- since that combination was clearly extensively tested.