# Why does "pip3 install pipenv" give error: ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'distlib'?

Tags: pip, alpine-linux, pipenv

How can I resolve the following error?

When trying to install `pipenv` on Alpine:

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

I get the following error:

```
Installing collected packages: distlib, virtualenv, pipenv
  Attempting uninstall: distlib
    Found existing installation: distlib 0.3.0
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'distlib'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Python version: 3.8.3
pip3 version: 20.2.2
Alpine version: 3.12 (Linux 5.4.43-1-virt #2-Alpine SMP Thu, 28 May 2020 20:13:48 UTC x86_64 Linux)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip cannot uninstall <package>: "It is a distutils installed project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807511/pip-cannot-uninstall-package-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Cannot+uninstall+a+distutils+installed+project+and+thus+we+cannot+accurately+determine+which+files+belong+to+it+which+would+lead+to+only+a+partial+uninstall

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install using the `--ignore-installed distlib` option to `pip3`:

```
pip3 install --ignore-installed distlib pipenv
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```