# Chatterbot corpus not found

Tags: python, installation, conda, pyyaml, chatterbot

I'm trying to build a simple chatbot using Chatterbot and use it's corpus.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot('Charlie')

corpus_trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)
corpus_trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.english')


response = chatbot.get_response(input())

print(response)
```

When I run, I get an error saying No such file or directory for the english corpus.

So I've tried installing chatterbot corpus by running `pip install chatterbot_corpus`, but keep getting the following error

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project
> and thus we cannot accurately determine  which files belong to it
> which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

I have also run `conda remove PyYAML` and tried again but still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to know what OS are you on. Because on Linux there is chance that `PyYAML` has been installed by OS and should be managed by OS-specific package manager.

Either way, you can just run pip with `--ignore-installed` switch and see what happens:

```
pip install --ignore-installed chatterbot_corpus
```

You can find more information on the nature of this error and more hints on the resolution in [this elaborate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53807588/6573902).