# getting unexpected error while executing the code (with sr.Microphone() as source:)

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, pyaudio

[image: image of the error]
I am making an Ai personal assistant on my laptop but i am getting this error.
I am using python version 3.10.4 and still i am getting this print error.
I am getting error in the line
with sr.Microphone() as source():
due to which even the microphone icon in the taskbar is not coming
plz do help to resolve it.
thanks.

i have installed pyaudio file from google
[image: this is the link which i have clicked]
[image: from this site]
plz tell how to resolve this.

error coming while upgrading pip to the latest version ----

C:\Users\DELL>pip install --upgrade pyaudio
Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.2.4)
Collecting pyaudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [9 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
Attempting uninstall: pyaudio
Found existing installation: PyAudio 0.2.4
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyAudio'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLl4G.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.xx, you can call print without parenthesis but in Python 3.xx, you need to call print with parenthesis. It seems like the version of pyaudio you are using is on Python 2.xx because the print statement where you are getting the error is missing parenthesis. Can you check your version of pyaudio? The latest version seems to be 0.2.11.

Comment: version= 0.2.4. i am not able to upgrade it using pip command

Comment: Remove it and then install again using pip: `pip install PyAudio==0.2.11`

Comment: Have a look at here as well regarding the uninstall issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807511/pip-cannot-uninstall-package-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project

Comment: not able to uninstall .error occurs=ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyAudio'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you are getting, you have not entered the other parenthesis at the end of the sentence. So try entering the missing parenthesis there.
If that doesn't work, try making another function like

```
def prn(text):
    print(text)
```

And then calling that function instead of the `print` function there.