# Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'

Tags: python, pip, python-module, llvmlite

I tried to install the modules from a requirements.txt file of a github project and it showed the following error.

ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Can you please help me figure out how to get it working..?

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqrPU.png)

Comment: How did you install llvmlite?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807511/pip-cannot-uninstall-package-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project

Comment: I just run the command 'pip install -r requirements.txt' and 'llvmlite==0.31.0' is one of the line in that file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.