# Cannot update TBB using pip: distutils installed project

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, dependencies, tbb

I ran a full update of all PyPi packages on my laptop (Ubuntu 22.04, Python 3.9), and I've resolved all dependency issues except one: Daal requires a different version of TBB than what I have. I forced an install of Daal just to have it, since I'm guessing some uses of it won't require TBB. However, when I try to install Daal without forcing, or try to update TBB, I get the following:

```
`Collecting tbb==2021.* (from daal)
  Obtaining dependency information for tbb==2021.* from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/a8/01ac205ff1f68f543aa73d69d6947218cd0973992a4b60cf0a4bfe507561/tbb-2021.10.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached tbb-2021.10.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.0 kB)
Using cached tbb-2021.10.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: tbb
  Attempting uninstall: tbb
    Found existing installation: TBB 0.2
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'TBB'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`
```

I first attempted to solve this problem using the following Stack Overflow page:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807511/pip-cannot-uninstall-package-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project)

I uninstalled the natively installed libtbb-dev, and reinstalled a version that would be compatible with my Daal package:

```
sudo apt install libtbb-dev
```

This installs libtbb-dev successfully:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libtbb12 libtbbmalloc2
Suggested packages:
  libtbb-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtbb-dev libtbb12 libtbbmalloc2
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
Need to get 325 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,893 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libtbbmalloc2 amd64 2021.5.0-7ubuntu2 [49.6 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libtbb12 amd64 2021.5.0-7ubuntu2 [84.8 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libtbb-dev amd64 2021.5.0-7ubuntu2 [191 kB]
Fetched 325 kB in 1s (425 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package libtbbmalloc2:amd64.
(Reading database ... 305019 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libtbbmalloc2_2021.5.0-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtbbmalloc2:amd64 (2021.5.0-7ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtbb12:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtbb12_2021.5.0-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtbb12:amd64 (2021.5.0-7ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtbb-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtbb-dev_2021.5.0-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtbb-dev:amd64 (2021.5.0-7ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libtbbmalloc2:amd64 (2021.5.0-7ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libtbb12:amd64 (2021.5.0-7ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libtbb-dev:amd64 (2021.5.0-7ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
```

However, this doesn't change the error message in pip.

I've also tried to use easy_install, but I can't get it working. I installed it with pip, but I can't import it into Python and Ubuntu doesn't recognize easy_install as a command.

What is TBB 0.2? I don't see that version number in the PyPi history.

Answer (score 1):

Please raise a query in oneAPI Registration, Download, Licensing and Installation [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/bd-p/registration-download-licensing-instal)!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pip show TBB 
Name: TBB
Version: 0.2
Summary: Python API for oneTBB
Home-page: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-tbb
Author: Intel Corporation
Author-email: inteltbbdevelopers@intel.com
License: Dual license: Apache or Proprietary
Location: /some/path/apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 
$
```

I think it is actually another packaging proving merely same files.

```
Collecting tbb>=2019.0 (from umap-learn>=0.3.10->scanpy>=1.8->splitpipe==1.1.2)
  Obtaining dependency information for tbb>=2019.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/fc/eeb2ab19f26e608bda910350b6f0a06e8dd1b472049b175ca36df93c81ff/tbb-2021.11.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Downloading tbb-2021.11.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.0 kB)
```

See https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/1008#issuecomment-1398095978 and https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/1263  .